# What are the reasons for using the meta tag "noindex, follow"?

Tags: seo, noindex, meta-robots

Besides using the meta tag for hiding, say, the sitemap to prevent your site appearing spammy, are there any other situations for using `noindex, follow`?

Comment: Why would you even use noindex, follow on a sitemap? also, Google and other search engines will never consider a legit sitemap spammy. You would normally only ever use `noindex, follow` on pages that you consider worthless to your users and the search engines. noindex shouldn't be used to on pages that are useful to your users.

Comment: ok I watched this video by Matt Cutts, but maybe it's outdated now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjRGkc__FwQ

Comment: Applying a "noindex" to an HTML sitemap is a good way to give search engines a harder time at indexing all important content, especially if you haven't submitted an XML based sitemap to search engines.

Comment: @Mike Not necessarily, providing the page is still "follow" (as stated in the question), then Google will still crawl the page and all its links, it's just that the page itself won't appear in the SERPs.

Answer (score 3):

Faceted navigation / search filtering allows visitors to narrow their search for specific products. Such navigation features generate crawl paths that are of no real value to a search engine but are useful for humans. By adding meta noindex,follow to these pages it instructs the search engine to crawl into the product pages for indexing but keeps the faceted search crawl paths out of their index. (keeping your site links from being bloated)

Comment: **This page is of no importance; however, its links are.** Layered Navigation/Search Refinement is heavy on duplicate content otherwise.